# Is there a way to use parameters with accessors in c#

Tags: c#, .net, accessor

I really like the syntax for accessors in c#, but I need to use some extra values in my setters for a few properties.

Is there any way I can do something similar to this or is it not possible with this type of syntax?

```
public class Accesssor{
    public List<CustomObject> AccessorStuff { 
        get {
                return AccessorStuff;
            } 
        set (ExtraParameters????) => {
                AccessorStuff.add(new CustomObject(value,ExtraParameters))
            }
        }
}
```

(I'm also finding this hard to search for because I don't know if this has an exact name, so if I could also get that piece of information I would massively appreciate it)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you are explaining a strange issue which is indeed difficult to understand. If you explained what result you are trying to do you might see that the solution you are looking for is something completely different.

Comment: It is valid in VB, not in C# beyond the indexer.  Even if you write the setter in VB then you still won't get to access it the normal way in C#, turns into a set_Accessor() method.  So you might as well make it a method.  Do beware that you are expected to pass a List<>, not a CustomObject, so you have no use for a property at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible - and not what I'd expect if I used your property. When I use `set` I expect to change the `List`, not add values to it. This is most commonly achieved via class methods:

```
public void AddObject(CustomObjectType obj, ExtraParameters extraParameters) => 
    AccessorStuff.Add(new CustomObject(obj, ExtraParameters));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a so called **indexer** in C#

```
public List<CustomObject> this[int index]
{
    get { /* return the specified index here */ }
    set { /* set the specified index to value here */ }
}
```

You can then access it with

```
obj[5] = someValue;
var result = obj[0];
```

Exactly as with methods, you can have any number of parameters (but at least one) of any type in indexers. You can also overload the indexer, i.e. have different versions with a different number of parameters or different parameter types. E.g.:

```
public List<CustomObject> this[string name]
{
    ...
}

public List<CustomObject> this[string name, bool caseSensitive]
{
    ...
}
```

But in any case the index applies to the setter as well as to the getter. Other than with properties, indexers cannot be named. If you need serveral such "properties" with parameters, just use plain old methods.

```
public void SetProperty(Extra stuff...)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The question was about using additional parameters for properties - indexers won't allow this additional degree of freedom.

Comment: In VB indexers are called **default properties**. They are exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @Tomer Actually Multi-Dimensiona arrays a are thing. And their indexers take multiple inputs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/#indexers-overview It is quite counter-intuitive for the reasons Turner listed. But is is an option. But at the end of the day, they are Syntax Sugar for set() and get() function pairs and do have full overload support.

Comment: @Christopher you are correct - I was referring to the answer as written, with one parameter.